# I get the error in php artisan route:list says Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::singularize() must be of the type string

Tags: laravel

Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::singularize() must be of the type string.
Im getting this error when a enter the php artisan route:list command, what should I do?

Comment: Can you check if your database connection works?

Comment: Yes, I can  perform crud.

Comment: my last changes in my project is the update of user profile when youre login

Comment: I'd suggest removing `vendor` folder and running `composer install`. If that does not help check if you have any Route which has closures inside. If you have closure please comment out that Route and try it again.

Comment: I commented all the closure routes and deleted vendor and composer install, but Nothing happen, same error,

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector::singularize() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\School\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer.php on line 86

  at C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\School\vendor\doctrine\inflector\lib\Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector.php:441
    437|      * @param string $word The word in plural form.

Comment: We need the whole stack trace for this one

Comment: anyways its laravel  with laravel nova administration panel, Ihave apply the make:auth in laravel, maybe it overwrite the function in user model in laravel nova, thats why i cant perform a route:list command. Do you a suggestion how to fix this?